# Does RLNC (Random Linear Network Coding) still need interaction from the other side to overcome packet loss reliably?

Tags: computer-networks, coding-theory

I'm looking into implementing RLNC as a project, and while I understand the concept of encoding the original data with random linear coefficients, resulting in a number of packets, sending those packets, and thus the client will be able to reconstruct the original data from some of the received packets, even if a few of the packets are lost, if enough encoded packets have arrived to create a solvable equation system.

However, I have not seen any mention of the fact that if there is a non zero percent of packet loss, there is a possibility that the receiver of the encoded packets will not receive enough packets to reconstruct the original data. The only solution I see to this is to implement some type of sequencing so that the receiver can verify he hasn't missed some packets that would allow him to reconstruct the original data, in other words interaction. Am I missing some part of the algorithm or not? If someone has solved this problem already, can you please show me where it has been solved so I can read about it?